# Is there any way to run a Blu-Ray player with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+?

Tags: pi-3b+

I realized the other day that instead of buying a new laptop for a single purpose such as this, I could possibly use my RPi3 B+. Unfortunately, I have not found any articles or contemporary mentions of doing this with success in my research and the only mentions of anything like this are 9 years old or more.
Thus, I ask, since 2012, has anyone successfully figured out a way to use a SATA Blu-ray player on a RPi3 B+? If so, I would much appreciate a detailed plan of action.

Comment: Are you talking about playing actual Bluray movies through the Pi?  Connecting the BluRay reader to the Pi is easy enough, and plenty of articles about playing BluRays in linux out there.  My concern would be the 1GB memory of the Pi 3B+ wouldn't be enough for smooth playback.

Comment: Yes, exactly, Bluray movies. How would I mitigate the smooth playback? Could I use an external hard drive?

Comment: If you rip the blueray to mkv, you can easily use Kodi for Raspberry Pi for direct playback from an external HDD.  VLC works too.  There are ways to play the discs directly, but i prefer the mkv method as it's all on the hard drive(s) and the disks can just go into storage after being ripped.  You could also setup a Plex server and play movies on the pi that way.